# grep through multiple files

Tags: shell, grep

I have directory where hundreds of files are written constantly. I want to grep these files for a pattern and then grep for pattern2 within those files and write the lines containing that pattern2 to a seperate file. I am using grep to do it.

```
grep pattern /dir/* | awk {'$1 = ""; print $0'} | grep pattern2 > $mydir/myDATA.txt
```

But the issue is with the files being written.
I am doing the above grep as part of a shell script which will run as a cron maybe every 5 mins to gather data.
Now, how can i make my script to skip the files it has already checked?
Another snippet i am doing from the myDATA.txt file is cut it to get the output i want in a certain format.

```
 array=$(cat /dir/myDATA.txt | tr "," "\n")
 for x in $array
 do
 bunch of stuff.
```

I have pretty much nailed this part. The only issue is with the files being written.
So I am expecting my script to look at files in directory, skip the ones it has already seen then run the grep command to output to a file and then modify that file a cleaned up and personalised output.

Comment: There's almost never a reason to pipe grep to awk, etc. like that. awk can do that pattern matching for you. Also if your lines don't start with a space or your filenames have a space in them that `$1 = ""` will not do what you are expecting it to (assuming you want it to drop the filename from the output). Use the grep `-h` argument to suppress that if you need to.

Comment: You could use the `find` command with the `-mmin` test to see which files have been modified within some time interval; e.g. `find /dir -mmin -5` to list files that were modified less than 5 minutes ago.

Comment: The reason I am doing that awk is because all my files start with pattern2. I want to eliminate that but check for the files to have pattern2.

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
1) create a list of the existing files in the directory filtered by a timestamp or a list of previously checked files
2) check through the files in a loop one by one
3) as you check each file either add it's name to a "done" list in another file or perhaps "touch" the files to update their timestamp if that is an acceptable option.
4) maintain the timestamp in a file of the last time you ran the cron job or subtract 5 minutes from the system time
5) Repeat
```

If that doesn't make sense please let me know.

Also you should be able to pass the results of the first grep directly to the second grep without using AWK in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tool like `inotifywait` to create events for new files. You can continuously filter and read from its output, then do your further processing on each new file. This way you do not need to implement a complex mechanism for keeping track of already visited files, and the files can be processed as soon as they are written.